MySQL select title and columns
I have this output:
SELECT Arquivo, Safra, LinhasA FROM t411 LIMIT 10;


I would like to get this kind of output:

Is there any way directly using SELECT?
... can also be by PROCEDURE if necessary.
I would really appreciate it if anyone can help.
I use MySQL Server (latest version) and run my selects through MySQL Workbench

I don't understand why you used limit 10 but, Can you try this?
select
Arquivo,
max(case when Safra = '2019/2020' then LinhasA else 0 end) as '2019/2020',
max(case when Safra = '2020/2021' then LinhasA else 0 end) as '2020/2021',
max(case when Safra = '2021/2022' then LinhasA ELSE 0 end) as '2021/2022'
from t411
group by 1;


Excelent! Tanks :)  .... I used limit just because the table is very long

@RuyHoffmann to help you in the future, this technique is called "conditional aggregation", and what you are trying to do is called a "pivot query".  some other database systems provide explicit syntax for pivot queries.  in mysql, if you know all the values you want to select up front, you do just do a conditional aggregation query; if not, you use dynamic sql (often in a procedure) to construct and execute a conditional aggregation query
